# Are there more people in Russia/Ukraine learning Chinese language than other white dominated countries?

Tags: learning

I only came up with this idea after I used wechat and VK and found some people from there can speak or are learning the language, while in Australia here I can hardly find any local people learning the language.

Are there more people in Russia/Ukraine learning Chinese? If this is the case, why?

Comment: First do some research and then edit your answer with the information you find. (It's not that we are not willing to help but the goal is to answer questions that you can't look up yourself). :-)

Comment: I couldnt find information about that on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the Ukrainians because absolutely have *no* idea what their deal is...

---

Russia and China have shared a fairly *close* relationship over the years.

China even has a minority called: **俄罗斯族** (Russian Minority in China):

## ABC Dictionary

> Russian ethnic minority in China

## A Chinese-English Dictionary

> the Russian nationality, or the Russians, distributed over the Xinjiang Uygur Autonomous Region and Heilongjiang Province

KEY, Oxford and CC-CEDICT dictionaries pretty much say the same thing(s).

Wikipedia has an article called History of [Sino-Russian relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Sino-Russian_relations) which says:

> China and Russia have generally had good relations since 1991.

and links to [Sino-Russian relations since 1991](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Russian_relations_since_1991) which says:

> Diplomatic relations between People's Republic of China and the Russian Federation dramatically improved after the dissolution of the Soviet Union and the establishment of the Russian Federation in 1991. The two countries share a long land border which was demarcated in 1991, and they signed a Treaty of Good-Neighborliness and Friendly Cooperation in 2001. On the eve of a 2013 state visit to Moscow by Chinese President Xi Jinping, Russian President Vladimir Putin remarked that the two nations were forging a special relationship.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Sino-Russian_relations)

Geography, residency and politics aside China has also taken many Russians songs and translated the lyrics and "covered" them in Chinese. Take 三套车 for instance - if you listen to it you can distinctly tell it's Russian (it has Russia written all over it!) but it's sung in Chinese!

There's that scene in *太阳照常升起* with the Russians and the Russian song too - sorry for the ambiguity but you just gotta see it yourself.

The point anyway is that -- Russia has made quite a big impact on the Chinese and China hasn't reject them like they have so many others (English abbreviations, like NBA, or words aren't even allowed in Chinese news).

So while there are quite a lot of Russians living in China, a lot have even grown up there - you can see from there relationship that they are quite "connected". So it doesn't seem like quite a *stretch* for Russians to learn Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

As a Ukrainian, I can tell that China is seen in my country as the next world's biggest economy and global power. And you can frequently hear sentiments like "China is on the rise" and even "the future belongs to Chinese".

So learning Chinese is rather seen as beneficial for one's career and/or for the future of one's children.

I personally know a girl from Kyiv who was persuaded by her father to go study Chinese in China. And now she has been living in China for the last three years.

P.S. As for the Australians, I am currently studying with a student from Australia in the University of Hong Kong. Even though he is in engineering major and a Caucasian, his Mandarin is very good and he speaks fluently with the Mainland students. So it's not like Australians don't learn Mandarin themselves.